# Enabling `Alt` hotkeys for buttons in Gnome?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

I mean: whenever a letter in the text of a button is underlined, pressing `Alt` plus that letter clicks the button.  I have gone through both the `Keyboard` and the `Tweak Tool` applets without success.

Pressing `Alt` does underline the letters, but I would prefer to have them underlined beforehand.

Comment: Afaik `gtk-enable-mnemonics` was deprecated in `gtk 3.10` so there's no way to toggle it to ON.

Comment: You are right.  This is unfortunate indeed. If you convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 6):

For GTK 2, add the following line to `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
gtk-auto-mnemonic = 0
```

For GTK 3 up to GTK 3.9:

```
do_dconf /org/gnome/desktop/interface/automatic-mnemonics false
```

In GTK 3.10, the option was removed (in [this commit](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/7e3a494fac62140f466fc43f6cc061215953e9b1), whose log message just states that the feature was removed). Looking at the source, there's no way to turn it on. The crazy behavior of showing the mnemonics only after <kbd>Alt</kbd> has been pressed for at least 300ms (the timeout is hardcoded as a compile-time constant) is the only possible one.

I set out to override this behavior by [preloading](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/) a library wrapper that forces mnemonics to be visible. It wasn't easy, because most of the calls are internal. I finally found a way to make the query that tells the label displayer whether the widget wants to display mnemonics always return true. It mostly works, I can see the mnemonics all the time in GEdit and Evince's dialog boxes, but not completely: some menu accelerators are missing, I don't know why.

The code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define PROP_MNEMONICS_VISIBLE 31

#ifdef DEBUG
#define DBG(args...) printf(args)
#else
#define DBG(args...)
#endif

static void (*original_gtk_window_get_property)(GObject *object, guint prop_id, GValue *value, GParamSpec *pspec);
static void wrap_gtk_window_get_property(GObject *object, guint prop_id, GValue *value, GParamSpec *pspec)
{
    original_gtk_window_get_property(object, prop_id, value, pspec);
    if (prop_id == PROP_MNEMONICS_VISIBLE) {
        DBG("%s(%p, %u, &%u, %p)\n", __FUNCTION__, object, prop_id, *(unsigned*)value, pspec);
        g_value_set_boolean(value, TRUE);
    }
}

inline void override_gtk_window_get_property(GType object_type, GObject *obj)
{
    static int first_window_creation = 1;
    if (object_type == GTK_TYPE_WINDOW && first_window_creation) {
        first_window_creation = 0;
        GtkWidgetClass *gtk_widget_class = GTK_WIDGET_GET_CLASS(obj);
        GObjectClass *gobject_class = G_OBJECT_CLASS(gtk_widget_class);
        original_gtk_window_get_property = gobject_class->get_property;
        gobject_class->get_property = wrap_gtk_window_get_property;
    }
}

GObject* g_object_new_valist(GType object_type, const gchar *first_property_name, va_list var_args)
{
    static GObject* (*original_g_object_new_valist)(GType object_type, const gchar *first_property_name, va_list var_args) = NULL;
    if (original_g_object_new_valist == NULL) {
        original_g_object_new_valist = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "g_object_new_valist");
    }
    GObject* obj = original_g_object_new_valist(object_type, first_property_name, var_args);
    override_gtk_window_get_property(object_type, obj);
    return obj;
}
gpointer g_object_new(GType object_type, const gchar *first_property_name, ...)
{
    va_list var_args;
    va_start(var_args, first_property_name);
    gpointer obj = g_object_new_valist(object_type, first_property_name, var_args);
    va_end(var_args);
    return obj;
}
gpointer g_object_newv(GType object_type, guint n_parameters, GParameter *parameters)
{
    static gpointer (*original_g_object_newv)(GType object_type, guint n_parameters, GParameter *parameters);
    if (original_g_object_newv == NULL) {
        original_g_object_newv = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "g_object_newv");
    }
    GObject* obj = original_g_object_newv(object_type, n_parameters, parameters);
    override_gtk_window_get_property(object_type, obj);
    return obj;
}
```

How to use it: write this to a file called `gtk_window_get_mnemonics_visible.c`. Install GCC and the GTK3 development package (e.g. `sudo apt-get install gcc libgtk-3-dev` on Debian/Ubuntu). Compile with

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -o gtk_window_get_mnemonics_visible.so gtk_window_get_mnemonics_visible.c
```

Run Gnome applications like this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/gtk_window_get_mnemonics_visible.so gedit
```

or put this in your `.profile`:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/gtk_window_get_mnemonics_visible.so
```

Note that `LD_PRELOAD` is a hack, it may cause weird behavior sometimes. I've only given this one a cursory test. Known bug:

- If `GTK_IM_MODULE` is set to `xim`, then using `LD_PRELOAD` for anything (even an empty C file!) causes GEdit to hang when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> (observed on Debian jessie). I have no idea why.