# How do I automatically show underlines for Alt+<letter> across XFCE user interface?

Tags: xfce

After installing xubuntu, I am by default able to press `Alt` to show unique letter underlines on buttons or tabs or menus, and then `Alt+<the underlined letter>` to select the appropriate item. This makes it possible to navigate most dialogues and system settings GUIs using the keyboard, which is very important for me for accessibility reasons.

How do I make it so it always shows those underlines, without having to hold `Alt` first?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Enabling `Alt` hotkeys for buttons in Gnome?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212470/enabling-alt-hotkeys-for-buttons-in-gnome) this feature was completely removed in gnome 3.10, which makes me assume that xfce just cannot do it (because it uses the same libraries underneath).